# Using copy.deepcopy on os.environ in python appears broken

Tags: python, environment-variables, deep-copy

I probably just missed some bit of documentation on how os.environ or copy.deepcopy works, but it appears that copy.deepcopy doesn't work on os.environ. But if I reconstruct the os.environ into a new dictionary, it works fine. Here's my example code:

```
import copy
import os

tcsh_loc = '/bin/tcsh'
safe_dict = {}
for key in os.environ.keys():
    safe_dict[key] = os.environ[key]

safe_dict['SAFE_ENV'] = 'non-leaked-var'
os.spawnv(os.P_WAIT, tcsh_loc, [tcsh_loc, '-c', 'echo $SAFE_ENV'])
os.spawnve(os.P_WAIT, tcsh_loc, [tcsh_loc, '-c', 'echo $SAFE_ENV'], safe_dict)

unsafe_dict = copy.deepcopy(os.environ)
unsafe_dict['UNSAFE_ENV'] = 'leaked-var'
os.spawnv(os.P_WAIT, tcsh_loc, [tcsh_loc, '-c', 'echo $UNSAFE_ENV'])
os.spawnve(os.P_WAIT, tcsh_loc, [tcsh_loc, '-c', 'echo $UNSAFE_ENV'], unsafe_dict)
```

What I expect to get out is:

```
SAFE_ENV: Undefined variable.
non-leaked-var
UNSAFE_ENV: Undefined variable.
leaked-var
```

But what I get out is:

```
SAFE_ENV: Undefined variable.
non-leaked-var
leaked-var
leaked-var
```

Which implies that somehow the `unsafe_dict['UNSAFE_ENV'] = 'leaked-var'` assignment somehow "leaks" into os.environ, presumably from os.environ not getting deepcopied as I expected.

I assume this is some kind of known behavior, but it seems really weird an undesirable to me, at least in terms of using things like os.spawnev(). I've got a clumsy workaround, but I'd be interested to understand what is going on and if there is a more elegant solution than a for loop...

Comment: And this is on Python 2.6 and also appears the same in 3.2.2

Comment: It's not weird.  Have you looked at the type of os.environ? It's not a list or something, it has its own methods etc, so it's clear it will modify the environment!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`os.environ` is of type `os._Environ`, not a list or dictionary.  It is logical that a copy of  an instance of `os._Environ` will modify the environment as well.

See the `os._Environ.__setitem__()` function. It stores the values in **2 places**, once using `putenv()` and one to assign the key in the `self._data` dictionary.

```
def __setitem__(self, key, value):
    key = self.encodekey(key)
    value = self.encodevalue(value)
    self.putenv(key, value)
    self._data[key] = value
```

Comment: I agree that it is it's own object, but that shouldn't prohibit copy from making a copy of the object. Also the documentation for os.spawn*e() shows using it as if it was a dict: `os.spawnvpe(os.P_WAIT, 'cp', L, os.environ)` from http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html?highlight=spawnve#os.spawnve

Comment: It does not prohibit making copies of it, but instances of `os._Environ` usually modify the environment variables.  `copy.deepcopy` creates real copies of objects, not fake copies in other types like `dict` or `list`.

Comment: Yes, `os.environ` *behaves* almost like a `dict`, but it is not.  It also modifies the shell environment when it is modified.

Comment: So, a os._Environ object is a frontend to the actual environment variables, and it's setter function calls putenv(), which affects the "actual" env, and it also has a cached copy in self._data() which is another copy. That's a bit weird. Why keep 2 copies of the env?

Comment: You still create a copy of an instance of `os._Environ` and `os._Environ` still modifies the environment and yes `self._data` is replicated to a new dictionary, but it is still contained in an instance of `os._Environ`...

Comment: So from looking at the source, I now understand that the setter in _Environ calls putenv(), which sets the key in some "other" place, which deepcopy clearly doesn't comprehend. But that raises the question of why are there 2 copies of the env?

Answer (score 1):

You can reconstruct it easier: Just use `dict(os.environ)`.

simple test:

```
import os
a=os.environ
b=dict(os.environ)

print type(a), type(b)
# -> <type 'instance'> <type 'dict'>

print a['PWD'], b['PWD']
# -> /home/max /home/max

b['PWD']='/fooo'
print a['PWD'], b['PWD']
# -> /home/max /fooo
```

Comment: `os.environ.copy` is a built-in version of this, and I'd recommend doing that instead.